# Neo4j 3.x LOAD CSV absolute file path

Tags: neo4j

In previous versions of Neo4j (2.X), LOAD CSV would take absolute path from

`LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///absolute/path/GraphExample2.csv' AS line`

However in 3.x, its appending it with `NEO4J_HOME` to that path.

How does one address absolute path for file imports?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your configuration file ([see here for the documented locations](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/)), comment out the [dbms.directories.import](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/#config_dbms.directories.import) setting. That will allow neo4j to use your path, as is.

**However, commenting out that setting [is not secure](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/#_load_csv), so do not do this on production servers.**

*NOTE: On my Mac, I have the desktop version of neo4j installed. The official documentation seems to have the wrong name for the config file. Mine is named `.neo4j.conf`, not `neo4j.conf`.*